# SWIG error: Using libnfc.c on python

Tags: python, nfc

I'm trying to use the C library libnfc for NFC Devices on python (http://nfc-tools.org/). With C I can run the example program and it works fine. I downloaded the package (https://code.google.com/p/pynfc/), which should allow to use the library on python and run the command "sudo python setup.py build_ext", like it is told in the README, but I get the following error:

```
running build_ext  
building '_nfc' extension  
swigging nfc.i to nfc_wrap.c  
swig -python -I/usr/include -module nfc -interface _nfc -O -o nfc_wrap.c nfc.i  
nfc/nfc.h:1489: Error: Syntax error in input(3).  
error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
```

This is the content of nfc.h:

```
typedef struct {  
  PyObject_HEAD  
  void *ptr; // <- line 1489  
  swig_type_info *ty;  
  int own;  
  PyObject *next;  
 #ifdef SWIGPYTHON_BUILTIN  
  PyObject *dict;  
 #endif  
} SwigPyObject;
```

I'm using Linux Mint 15.

Thanks to everyone who takes the time to read this!

Answer (score 0):

[SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) is a software development tool that connects programs written in C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages.

So, just try:

```
apt-get install swig
```

Comment: I had to install swig long before I arrived this error ;) I'm running the newest version of swig.